# R dplyr rename dropping other variables?

Tags: r, select, dplyr, rename

I am trying to use dplyr to rename multiple variables, but then I lose access to other columns that I do not rename, which is not what I expect from the documentation. Note I got this to work using the plyr version of rename, but want to use dplyr version to avoid some hairy conflicts between plyr and dplyr.

Example:

```
airports_dest <- nycflights13::airports %>% 
  rename(lat = lat_dest, lon = lon_dest)) %>% 
  select(faa,lat_dest, lon_dest)
```

Yields error:

```
Error in select(faa, lat_dest, lon_dest) : object 'faa' not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you reported is caused by an extra `)` at the end of your `rename` call.

The columns are already named 'lat' and 'lon' in the dataset. If you want to rename them as 'lat_dest' and 'lon_dest', flip the `rename` parameters around.

```
airports_dest <- 
    nycflights13::airports %>% 
    rename(lat_dest = lat, lon_dest = lon) %>%
    select(faa, lat_dest, lon_dest)

head(airports_dest)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   faa   lat_dest lon_dest
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 04G       41.1    -80.6
#> 2 06A       32.5    -85.7
#> 3 06C       42.0    -88.1
#> 4 06N       41.4    -74.4
#> 5 09J       31.1    -81.4
#> 6 0A9       36.4    -82.2
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the fix DuckyPyjamas. I clearly tripped myself up mapping plyr rename into dplyr rename.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
airports_dest <- 
  nycflights13::airports %>% 
  select(faa, lat_dest = lat, lon_dest = lon)
```